# is there a way to install css bootstrap in public folder rather that node-module folder as a default?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install **bootstrap** with this command `**npm install bootstrap@3**` in my node js app. Although I navigated to the **public folder** ( i.e cd public ), but I found the bootstrap folder in the **node-module folder** after installation

I know I can use **Bower**, but I want to know if this can be done first.

Comment: If you don't want to install bootstrap using npm. Then consider it adding as an external css file in your index.html file and place the bootstrap.min.css file there.

Comment: You can also just npm install it and then copy paste the css to your desired location